# How to create a new message folder in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to develop a thunderbird extension and i need to create a message folder in folder pane where to move some messages.Can anyone help me how to create that folder.

Answer (score 0):

[This Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Available_libraries) helped me a lot. Check the chapter "Creating Folders".
It says something like this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");  
var folder = FileUtils.getDir("ProfD", ["FolderName"], true);
```

You can replace `"ProfD"` with another string ([more strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Getting_files_in_special_directories)).